# Rxjava why did not execute the onNext method

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android

I wrote a method to print the output from flatMap （Pseudo code）:

```
Observable.just(...).repeat()
    .flatMap( return Observable.just([double]))
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Subscriber<Double>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            tvConfidence.setText(e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Double aDouble) {
            tvConfidence.setText("Confidence :" + aDouble);
        }
    });
```

When I run these code, it works a few seconds but after a few seconds, it would not run onto the `onNext` method again. I don't know why, because I debug the code, it will run the `Observable.just(double)`, and the value always changed but it would not execute the code `setText` to refresh the `textView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that due to that particular `flatMap` overload, you eventually start to accumulate a lot of `just` because `flatMap` is unbounded-in. Try with `flatMap(f, 1)` to limit the concurrency level.

Comment: Thank u! I change the flatMap to map, and it works.Maybe I should not use the flatMap in this case.